# Live stream video of Selenium scripts/bots

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, video-streaming, live-streaming

I would like to stream video footage of running Selenium scripts/bots. I'm using [capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) with [selenium-webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/rb) and I know I can use [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless#capturing-video) to capture video.

What I don't know how to do is stream the video such that I can access it at some URL and not consume disk space. Has anyone done this?

Here's a test script I use to generate video files:

```
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'

Capybara.configure do |c|
  c.javascript_driver = :selenium
  c.default_driver = :selenium
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  profile['general.useragent.override'] = Bot::USER_AGENT
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, { 
    browser: :chrome,
    profile: profile,
    args: ['--window-size=1024,768'] 
  })
end

class Bot
  include Capybara::DSL

  USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'

  def run
    headless = Headless.new
    headless.start
    headless.video.start_capture

    loop do
      visit('http://google.com')
      sleep 1
      visit('http://youtube.com')
      sleep 1
      headless.video.stop_and_save("video-#{Time.now.to_i}.mov")
    end
  end
end

bot = Bot.new
bot.run
```

Comment: I looked into this a while ago and wasn't able to figure it out then, but I can give you a lead. Looking at [How to validate Streaming/ video output?](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6318) on Selenium's issue page, it seems it's not supported by that tool. But I think headless could be configured to create fragmented mp4s, which from my understanding are streamable. See the issue I raised on headless' github page: [How could I produce a fragmented mp4?](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/issues/79)

Comment: @maxpleaner I actually saw your question a while back and became discouraged by the repo owner's answer. I'll try out the fragmented mp4s though. The thing I'm confused about is won't these fragmented mp4 files pile up and consume disk space indefinitely? My scripts run forever.

Comment: you could delete them after sending

Comment: Are you able to pipe the video anywhere, such as to FFmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. Here's the updated Ruby script:

```
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'

Capybara.configure do |c|
  c.javascript_driver = :selenium
  c.default_driver = :selenium
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  profile['general.useragent.override'] = Bot::USER_AGENT
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    browser: :chrome,
    profile: profile,
    args: ["--window-size=1024,768"]
  })
end

class Bot
  include Capybara::DSL

  USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'
  FILE_PATH = File.join(__dir__, 'segment%05d.ts')

  def run
    headless = Headless.new(video: {
      codec: 'libx264',
      frame_rate: 25,
      tmp_file_path: FILE_PATH,
      extra: [
        '-pix_fmt yuv420p',
        '-profile:v baseline',
        '-b:v 1500k',
        '-x264opts keyint=25',
        '-s 640x360',
        '-map 0',
        '-flags',
        '-global_header',
        '-f segment',
        '-segment_list index_1500.m3u8',
        '-segment_time 1',
        '-segment_format mpeg_ts',
        '-segment_list_type m3u8',
        '-segment_list_flags +live',
        '-segment_list_size 2',
      ],
    })
    headless.start
    headless.video.start_capture

    loop do
      print 'loading google... '
      visit('http://google.com')
      puts 'done'
      print 'loading youtube... '
      visit('http://youtube.com')
      puts 'done'
    end
  end
end

bot = Bot.new
bot.run
```

Internally, `headless` will build this command:

```
/usr/bin/avconv -y -r 25 -s 1280x1024 -f x11grab -i :99 -g 600 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -b:v 1500k -x264opts keyint=25 -s 640x360
 -map 0 -flags -global_header -f segment -segment_list index_1500.m3u8 -segment_time 1 -segment_format mpeg_ts -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_flags +li
ve -segment_list_size 2 /home/mhluska/record-test/segment%05d.ts
```

I'm not well versed in `ffmpeg` so I can't explain what half of these parameters do. The end result is it will produce `segment*.ts` files and `index_1500.m3u8` which seems to be a manifest.

We can play it in the browser now. Create `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video stream test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="index_1500.m3u8" autoplay controls type="application/x-mpegURL"></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

And serve it temporarily with `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`.

Notes/caveats:

- I had to first set up a [swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) on my VPS otherwise the script would get killed
- The `video` tag seems to only play on Safari and not Chrome
- The video ratio/size seems wrong but this can be corrected by tweaking the `ffmpeg` parameters